# Django Зачем нужно include(..., namespace='')?

Tags: python, django, namespace

Я в `index/urls.py` написал что-то типа того:

```
app_name='index'
urlpatterns = [
  ...
]
```

Если я в `project/urls.py` напишу так:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('index.urls'))
   ...
]
```

А потом так:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('index.urls', namespace='index'))
   ...
]
```

То я замечу, что ничего не меняется, хотя в книге написано, что в `url-адресе` должна меняться приставка (которой у меня нет), но абсолютно ничего не происходит.

Прошу объяснить что делает параметр `namespace`, и когда его нужно применять, (желательно с примером).

**Заранее спасибо!)**

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то их ввели для include урлов из других смежных приложений

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: Пространства имён нужны переиспользуемому коду. Написали вы например какую-то батарейку, опубликовали её, человек её подключил себе в проект, а у него такие же паттерны URL'ов используются - всё сломается. Ещё иногда бывает необходимость один django app подключить несколько раз, для обслуживания разных корней, в этом тоже не обойтись без пространств имён.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы меня возможно не поняли, у меня параметр `namespace` НИЧЕГО не делает, а если написать этот параметр без app_name, то будет ошибка! И я бы не отказался от примера с кодом))

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 насколько я понял из документации, параметр `namespace` - это пространство имен пространства имен